# Creating a CSV file containing names of files within a directory

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, awk, sed

I am stuck on this projet , I need to create a cvs file of a list of files in a directory .

right now I'm using ls -la > test.csv which works but i need to separate the file permissions , date , file name . i also need to cut up the file into three parts

heres the raw format

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 heta-Sxl heta-SXL 677 Apr  5 13:36 move_20160403234624_SXL_Q97GN_238.tgz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 heta-Sxl heta-SXL 678 Apr  5 13:37 move_20160403234624_SXL_Q97GN_239.tgz
```

This what I'm trying to do

```
Permissions  file size  Date   time filename1                filename 2  filename 3
-rw-rw-r--    677       APR 5  13:37 move_20160403234624_SXL  Q97GN        239
```

Comment: cut command can help you : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm

Comment: Do you want commas as separators in your output file?

Comment: yes commas would be great , i need to input this into a mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

add the header...

```
$ awk '{split($9,f,"_");sub(/\..*/,"",f[5]);
       print $1, $5,$6,$7,$8,f[1]"_"f[2]"_"f[3],f[4],f[5]}' test.csv

-rw-rw-r-- 677 Apr 5 13:36 move_20160403234624_SXL Q97GN 238
-rw-rw-r-- 678 Apr 5 13:37 move_20160403234624_SXL Q97GN 239
```

you can pipe in `ls` output directly as well without the intermediary file

```
$ ls -la | awk ...
```

Comment: how do i run this?

Comment: do i run this like this ls -la | awk ?

Comment: yes, the same awk script few lines above without the file name at the end.

Comment: Note that `ls -l` changes its date/time format depending on the age of the file.  You may get date and time or date and year.  Use the `--time-style` option, if available, to give a consistent format (e.g. `--time-style=long-iso`).  Note also that the '-a' option to `ls` will cause lines to be output for '.' and '..'.  You probably just want `ls -l`.

Comment: Why not generate `INSERT INTO` statements with awk ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ls`, you can use `find` to do the main part of the job and then awk (or sed) to split the filename:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%M\t%s\t%Tb %Td\t%TH:%TM\t%f\n" | awk -F'[_.]' -v OFS='_' '{print $1,$2,$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}'
```